# JSON String to Dictionary in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, swift4, swifty-json, nsjsonserialization

I'm getting response from server in JSON in this format.

```
{"ResponseCode":1,"StudentDetails":[{"Student_ID":1,"Student_SchoolID":1,"Student_BranchID":1,"Student_ClassID":1,"Student_FirstName":"1","Student_MiddleName":"","Student_LastName":"","Student_Gender":"Male","Student_DOB":"19/03/2017","Student_EnrollmentNo":"1","Class_Name":"1 QA","Student_Password":"123456","Student_PrimaryEmailID":"","SchoolLogo":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1/uploadeddocs/branch/compress/images106472017105803.jpg","Student_IsProfileImageUpload":true,"Student_IsSoftDelete":false,"Student_IsActive":true,"Branch_Name":"1","ProfilePicture":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1/uploadeddocs/student/compress/IMG100710620180809104233860.JPG","DatabaseID":106,"IsSMSDisabled":false,"SMSBalance":null,"SMSSettingID":0,"NotificationSettingID":0,"IsSuperAdminUser":false,"SelectedSessionMasterID":0,"TargetedDate":null,"SelectedSessionType":0},{"Student_ID":278324,"Student_SchoolID":1404,"Student_BranchID":1408,"Student_ClassID":14193,"Student_FirstName":"Ganu now","Student_MiddleName":"","Student_LastName":"","Student_Gender":"Male","Student_DOB":"01/01/0001","Student_EnrollmentNo":"","Class_Name":"1 QA","Student_Password":"123456","Student_PrimaryEmailID":"","SchoolLogo":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1/uploadeddocs/branch/compress/images106472017105803.jpg","Student_IsProfileImageUpload":false,"Student_IsSoftDelete":false,"Student_IsActive":true,"Branch_Name":"1","ProfilePicture":"","DatabaseID":106,"IsSMSDisabled":false,"SMSBalance":null,"SMSSettingID":0,"NotificationSettingID":0,"IsSuperAdminUser":false,"SelectedSessionMasterID":0,"TargetedDate":null,"SelectedSessionType":0},{"Student_ID":267971,"Student_SchoolID":1404,"Student_BranchID":1408,"Student_ClassID":4894,"Student_FirstName":"Poonam Dillo saii","Student_MiddleName":"","Student_LastName":"","Student_Gender":"Male","Student_DOB":"01/01/0001","Student_EnrollmentNo":"2211","Class_Name":"Nursery A","Student_Password":"123456","Student_PrimaryEmailID":"","SchoolLogo":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1/uploadeddocs/branch/compress/images106472017105803.jpg","Student_IsProfileImageUpload":true,"Student_IsSoftDelete":false,"Student_IsActive":true,"Branch_Name":"1","ProfilePicture":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1/uploadeddocs/student/compress/FB_IMG_145451330612110622062018203844.jpg","DatabaseID":106,"IsSMSDisabled":false,"SMSBalance":null,"SMSSettingID":0,"NotificationSettingID":0,"IsSuperAdminUser":false,"SelectedSessionMasterID":0,"TargetedDate":null,"SelectedSessionType":0},{"Student_ID":272466,"Student_SchoolID":1404,"Student_BranchID":1408,"Student_ClassID":14193,"Student_FirstName":"Poonam ganu","Student_MiddleName":"","Student_LastName":"","Student_Gender":"Male","Student_DOB":"01/01/0001","Student_EnrollmentNo":"","Class_Name":"1 QA","Student_Password":"123456","Student_PrimaryEmailID":"","SchoolLogo":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1/uploadeddocs/branch/compress/images106472017105803.jpg","Student_IsProfileImageUpload":false,"Student_IsSoftDelete":false,"Student_IsActive":true,"Branch_Name":"1","ProfilePicture":"","DatabaseID":106,"IsSMSDisabled":false,"SMSBalance":null,"SMSSettingID":0,"NotificationSettingID":0,"IsSuperAdminUser":false,"SelectedSessionMasterID":0,"TargetedDate":null,"SelectedSessionType":0},{"Student_ID":273560,"Student_SchoolID":1404,"Student_BranchID":1408,"Student_ClassID":14564,"Student_FirstName":"Ganesh kumar saini","Student_MiddleName":"","Student_LastName":"","Student_Gender":"Male","Student_DOB":"01/01/0001","Student_EnrollmentNo":"","Class_Name":"Primary","Student_Password":"123456","Student_PrimaryEmailID":"","SchoolLogo":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1/uploadeddocs/branch/compress/images106472017105803.jpg","Student_IsProfileImageUpload":false,"Student_IsSoftDelete":false,"Student_IsActive":true,"Branch_Name":"1","ProfilePicture":"","DatabaseID":106,"IsSMSDisabled":false,"SMSBalance":null,"SMSSettingID":0,"NotificationSettingID":0,"IsSuperAdminUser":false,"SelectedSessionMasterID":0,"TargetedDate":null,"SelectedSessionType":0},{"Student_ID":133262,"Student_SchoolID":1404,"Student_BranchID":1408,"Student_ClassID":5065,"Student_FirstName":"Lavish saini","Student_MiddleName":"","Student_LastName":"","Student_Gender":"Male","Student_DOB":"04/02/2018","Student_EnrollmentNo":"09EEBMIT29","Class_Name":"KG ICA","Student_Password":"123456","Student_PrimaryEmailID":"ganeshsaini01@gmail.com","SchoolLogo":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1/uploadeddocs/branch/compress/images106472017105803.jpg","Student_IsProfileImageUpload":true,"Student_IsSoftDelete":false,"Student_IsActive":true,"Branch_Name":"1","ProfilePicture":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1/uploadeddocs/student/compress/download110682201811024710015409877121411061541069294120.jpg","DatabaseID":106,"IsSMSDisabled":false,"SMSBalance":null,"SMSSettingID":0,"NotificationSettingID":0,"IsSuperAdminUser":false,"SelectedSessionMasterID":0,"TargetedDate":null,"SelectedSessionType":0}],"StudentMenusCount":[{"CountValue":0,"StudentId":0,"CountFor":"StudyPlanner","DatabaseID":0,"IsSMSDisabled":false,"SMSBalance":null,"SMSSettingID":0,"NotificationSettingID":0,"IsSuperAdminUser":false,"SelectedSessionMasterID":0,"TargetedDate":null,"SelectedSessionType":0}]}
```

Now this I'm getting in JSON String format. I need to convert it to Dictionary. I'm using this code to parse json.

```
let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as Any

if myJson is String {
    print(myJson) // Printing Here as myJson is String.
}
```

If I'm writing in above code as:

```
let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
```

It's complaining about bad json than. Any idea of how to convert json string to Dictionary here?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. – What is the exact error message?

Comment: With any valid json, there should not be any error. Check your response where its failing to serialize and verify the json.

Answer (score 4):

This is the way to do it but you should say what is the error:

```
 if let data = Data(result.utf8) {
  do {
     let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String: Any]

 } catch let error {
        print(error)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the JSON is fine, however the way you parse JSON is not.

I tried with this code and the result is expected.

```
let response = """
{"ResponseCode":1,"StudentDetails":[{"Student_ID":1,"Student_SchoolID":1,"Student_BranchID":1,"Student_ClassID":1,"Student_FirstName":"1","Student_MiddleName":"","Student_LastName":"","Student_Gender":"Male","Student_DOB":"19/03/2017","Student_EnrollmentNo":"1","Class_Name":"1 QA","Student_Password":"123456","Student_PrimaryEmailID":"","SchoolLogo":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1/uploadeddocs/branch/compress/images106472017105803.jpg","Student_IsProfileImageUpload":true,"Student_IsSoftDelete":false,"Student_IsActive":true,"Branch_Name":"1","ProfilePicture":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1/uploadeddocs/student/compress/IMG100710620180809104233860.JPG","DatabaseID":106,"IsSMSDisabled":false,"SMSBalance":null,"SMSSettingID":0,"NotificationSettingID":0,"IsSuperAdminUser":false,"SelectedSessionMasterID":0,"TargetedDate":null,"SelectedSessionType":0},{"Student_ID":278324,"Student_SchoolID":1404,"Student_BranchID":1408,"Student_ClassID":14193,"Student_FirstName":"Ganu now","Student_MiddleName":"","Student_LastName":"","Student_Gender":"Male","Student_DOB":"01/01/0001","Student_EnrollmentNo":"","Class_Name":"1 QA","Student_Password":"123456","Student_PrimaryEmailID":"","SchoolLogo":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1/uploadeddocs/branch/compress/images106472017105803.jpg","Student_IsProfileImageUpload":false,"Student_IsSoftDelete":false,"Student_IsActive":true,"Branch_Name":"1","ProfilePicture":"","DatabaseID":106,"IsSMSDisabled":false,"SMSBalance":null,"SMSSettingID":0,"NotificationSettingID":0,"IsSuperAdminUser":false,"SelectedSessionMasterID":0,"TargetedDate":null,"SelectedSessionType":0},{"Student_ID":267971,"Student_SchoolID":1404,"Student_BranchID":1408,"Student_ClassID":4894,"Student_FirstName":"Poonam Dillo saii","Student_MiddleName":"","Student_LastName":"","Student_Gender":"Male","Student_DOB":"01/01/0001","Student_EnrollmentNo":"2211","Class_Name":"Nursery A","Student_Password":"123456","Student_PrimaryEmailID":"","SchoolLogo":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1/uploadeddocs/branch/compress/images106472017105803.jpg","Student_IsProfileImageUpload":true,"Student_IsSoftDelete":false,"Student_IsActive":true,"Branch_Name":"1","ProfilePicture":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1/uploadeddocs/student/compress/FB_IMG_145451330612110622062018203844.jpg","DatabaseID":106,"IsSMSDisabled":false,"SMSBalance":null,"SMSSettingID":0,"NotificationSettingID":0,"IsSuperAdminUser":false,"SelectedSessionMasterID":0,"TargetedDate":null,"SelectedSessionType":0},{"Student_ID":272466,"Student_SchoolID":1404,"Student_BranchID":1408,"Student_ClassID":14193,"Student_FirstName":"Poonam ganu","Student_MiddleName":"","Student_LastName":"","Student_Gender":"Male","Student_DOB":"01/01/0001","Student_EnrollmentNo":"","Class_Name":"1 QA","Student_Password":"123456","Student_PrimaryEmailID":"","SchoolLogo":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1/uploadeddocs/branch/compress/images106472017105803.jpg","Student_IsProfileImageUpload":false,"Student_IsSoftDelete":false,"Student_IsActive":true,"Branch_Name":"1","ProfilePicture":"","DatabaseID":106,"IsSMSDisabled":false,"SMSBalance":null,"SMSSettingID":0,"NotificationSettingID":0,"IsSuperAdminUser":false,"SelectedSessionMasterID":0,"TargetedDate":null,"SelectedSessionType":0},{"Student_ID":273560,"Student_SchoolID":1404,"Student_BranchID":1408,"Student_ClassID":14564,"Student_FirstName":"Ganesh kumar saini","Student_MiddleName":"","Student_LastName":"","Student_Gender":"Male","Student_DOB":"01/01/0001","Student_EnrollmentNo":"","Class_Name":"Primary","Student_Password":"123456","Student_PrimaryEmailID":"","SchoolLogo":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1/uploadeddocs/branch/compress/images106472017105803.jpg","Student_IsProfileImageUpload":false,"Student_IsSoftDelete":false,"Student_IsActive":true,"Branch_Name":"1","ProfilePicture":"","DatabaseID":106,"IsSMSDisabled":false,"SMSBalance":null,"SMSSettingID":0,"NotificationSettingID":0,"IsSuperAdminUser":false,"SelectedSessionMasterID":0,"TargetedDate":null,"SelectedSessionType":0},{"Student_ID":133262,"Student_SchoolID":1404,"Student_BranchID":1408,"Student_ClassID":5065,"Student_FirstName":"Lavish saini","Student_MiddleName":"","Student_LastName":"","Student_Gender":"Male","Student_DOB":"04/02/2018","Student_EnrollmentNo":"09EEBMIT29","Class_Name":"KG ICA","Student_Password":"123456","Student_PrimaryEmailID":"ganeshsaini01@gmail.com","SchoolLogo":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1/uploadeddocs/branch/compress/images106472017105803.jpg","Student_IsProfileImageUpload":true,"Student_IsSoftDelete":false,"Student_IsActive":true,"Branch_Name":"1","ProfilePicture":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1/uploadeddocs/student/compress/download110682201811024710015409877121411061541069294120.jpg","DatabaseID":106,"IsSMSDisabled":false,"SMSBalance":null,"SMSSettingID":0,"NotificationSettingID":0,"IsSuperAdminUser":false,"SelectedSessionMasterID":0,"TargetedDate":null,"SelectedSessionType":0}],"StudentMenusCount":[{"CountValue":0,"StudentId":0,"CountFor":"StudyPlanner","DatabaseID":0,"IsSMSDisabled":false,"SMSBalance":null,"SMSSettingID":0,"NotificationSettingID":0,"IsSuperAdminUser":false,"SelectedSessionMasterID":0,"TargetedDate":null,"SelectedSessionType":0}]}
"""

if let data = response.data(using: .utf8) {
  let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, 
                                                options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as Any

  if myJson is String {
    print(myJson) // <-- This will not print anything as myJson is not a string
  }

  if let dict = myJson as? [String: Any] {
    print(dict.keys) // <-- This will print a list of keys 
  }
}
```